# Find and Get ID with two arrays Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, object, multidimensional-array

So I have to csv, one of them contains "Tshirt, ID" and the other one contains only the Tshirt.

After using papaparse I got two arrays like this:

```
[]
data: Array(6)
0: {tshirt: "a", ID: 121}
1: {tshirt: "b", ID: 132}
2: {tshirt: "c", ID: 147}
3: {tshirt: "d", ID: 97}
4: {tshirt: "e", ID: 76}

[]
data: Array(2)
0: {tshirt: "d", ID: null}
1: {tshirt: "a", ID: null}
```

What I want to do is generate a new csv with the second array + the ID from the first array.
Something like this :

```
[]
data: Array(2)
0: {tshirt: "d", ID: 97}
1: {tshirt: "a", ID: 121}
```

I've tried everything and I cant make it work. here is my code:

```
    var data1=  []
    Papa.parse('a.csv', {
      header: true,
      delimiter: ';',
      download: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: function(results) {
        data1.data = results.data
      }
    });

    var data2 = []
    Papa.parse('b.csv', {
      header: true,
      delimiter: ';',
      download: true,
      dynamicTyping: true,
      skipEmptyLines: true,
      complete: function(results) {
        data2.data = results.data
      }
    });

console.log(data1)
console.log(data2)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the relationship between `d` and `97`? According to what logic are those two joined together?

Comment: You say you've tried everything but you're only showing us that you are logging out the results from the parse. Can you post the code you have where you attempt to merge the arrays?

Comment: The not optimized way is to loop ( `.map()` ) over data2. Inside the loop of data2, loop over data1 ( `.find()` ) to find the object where the tshirts match. Then just return a new object with the tshirt name from data2 and the id from data1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, that's creating a map from first array:

```
const data1 = 
[{tshirt: "a", ID: 121},
{tshirt: "b", ID: 132},
{tshirt: "c", ID: 147},
{tshirt: "d", ID: 97},
{tshirt: "e", ID: 76}]

const data2 = 
[{tshirt: "d", ID: null},
{tshirt: "a", ID: null}]

const data1map = data1.reduce ((acc, d) => ({...acc, [d.tshirt]: d}), {})

const result = data2.map(d => ({...d, ID: data1map[d.tshirt].ID}))
```